# two image shown into one lightbox

Tags: lightbox

I have to image with the following code:

```
  echo '<div class="thumb" style="width: '.$array['thumb_width'].'px; height: '.$array['thumb_height'].'px;">
            <a class="lightbox" width="72" height="72" href="showfile.php?image_id='.$array['before_image_id'].'" >
            <img src="showthumbs.php?image_id='.$array['before_image_id'].'"/">
            </a>

            <a class="lightbox" width="72" height="72" href="showfile.php?image_id='.$array['after_image_id'].'" >
            <img src="showthumbs.php?image_id='.$array['after_image_id'].'"/">
            </a>

            </div><p><p/>';
```

The issue is that it is displayed separately in the lightbox. I want it to show two image side by side in one lightbox.. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options, depending on the lightbox you're using:

1. Some lightboxes (colorbox, DOM window, facybox, thickbox) support loading html pages into an iframe rather than just images. If you can try loading html with the two  tags into the lightbox.
2. If you have a lightbox that only supports images (like squarespace's crappy lightbox) you may have to merge the images together using PHP's GD library.
   See this question:
   [Merge Two images together on Server, then save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317627/merge-two-images-together-on-server-then-save)

Comment: do you know if this http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ can do html?

Comment: and can you give me an example of using fancybox to do this? I see on their website that they can do inline content not sure how

Comment: I don't think that lightbox supports iframes.

Comment: with fancybox look into the api page
http://fancybox.net/api

set the type to be iframe and then you can just have a link to a html or php page and it will open in the fancybox:
This is the javascript (don't forget to include the jQuery library and the fancybox library).
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("a.fancy").fancybox({
  'type' : 'iframe',
  'width' : 500,
  'height'  : 400, 
 });
 
});

and then this html

<a href="page.php" class="fancy">show fancybox</a>